# IMA.js skeleton install: Cannot find module v8flags

Tags: gulp, ima.js

I've tried to install hello world application with this command:

```
gulp app:hello
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\gulp\node_modules\v8flags\3.28.73.flags.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\gulp\bin\gulp.js:25:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have old version of Gulp.

Try to reinstall with `npm install --global gulp`.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, can't find fibers.
Here is a link to my npm-error-log:
https://gist.github.com/anthonybrown/e2108d14870f5636fc26132dd932ce5b